# how make binary varibale with specific structure - php

Tags: php

I want to cmmunicate with a udp tracker and send a connect request to it.

for this i must at first create a 16-bytes variable in php and sends it to the tracker.

request variable structure:

put it first 64-bit 0x41727101980  and 32-bit with 0.

generate a 32-bit unsigned integer as random and then add generated number to end of the variable.

finally, the size of my variable should be 128-bit equal to 16-bytes.

I use this way:

```
$a = time();
$connect_request = 0x41727101980;
$connect_request .= 0x00000000;
$connect_request .= $a;
var_dump($connect_request);
```

but result is:

```
string '449748612544001413719239' (length=24)
```

this is 24-byte not 16-byte.

what I must do now ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have there are numbers.

Try this:

```
$connect_request = pack("N*",0x417,0x27101980,0,time());
```

If you have PHP 5.6 then you can use `pack("JN*", 0x41727101980, 0, time())`, allowing for direct 64-bit number use, but otherwise you will need to manually split the big number into two smaller numbers (each 32-bit, hence the second `0x...` having eight hexits).

This will pack the inputs into a string of your desired length, in this case 128-bit, or 24 bytes.